# How to handle OpenGL additive blending and depth test with particles and deeper objects

Tags: c++, c, opengl, shader, particle-system

I have a little sprites particle system made with OpenGL & glut using textures to draw a basic flame. The flame is reproduced symmetrically to illustrate how it behaves in a little box/scene. And as the pictures below demonstrate, there are two problems:

1- To produce a somewhat good looking flame effect I want to use additive blending with my particles, but the blending also takes the color of the deeper cyan panel into account and produce a white flame.

[image: Additive blending not working with colored background]

2.1 - Also, to achieve a correct implementation of the additive blending I have to disable the depth test while drawing the particles, but doing so enable the drawing of particles even if they should be "hidden".

[image: Depth test]

2.2 - If I enable the depth test while drawing the particles, here is what it looks like.

[image: Depth test enabled]

If it is of any help, here is the texture I am applying to the particles.

[image: Explosion texture]

Here is the relevant code that displays the scene and the particles.

```
void drawParticles()
{
   glPushAttrib(GL_ALL_ATTRIB_BITS);
   glDisable(GL_LIGHTING);
   glDisable(GL_DEPTH_TEST);
   glEnable(GL_TEXTURE_2D);
   glEnable(GL_BLEND);
   glBlendFunc(GL_SRC_ALPHA,GL_ONE);
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D,explosionTexture[0]);
   glTexEnvi(GL_POINT_SPRITE, GL_COORD_REPLACE, GL_TRUE);

   for (int i = 0; i < particlesNumber; ++i) 
   {
    glPointSize(50.0f);
        glBegin(GL_POINTS);
            glColor4f(particlesArray[i].color[0],particlesArray[i].color[1],particlesArray[i].color[2],0.5f);
            glVertex3f(particlesArray[i].position[0],particlesArray[i].position[1],particlesArray[i].position[2]);
       glEnd();
   }
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);
   glDisable( GL_BLEND );
   glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
   glPopAttrib();
}

void drawScene()
{
   glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );

   glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
   glLoadIdentity();
   gluPerspective( 60.0f, (GLdouble) g_width / (GLdouble) g_height, 0.1f, 300.0f );

   glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
   glLoadIdentity();

   gluLookAt( dist*sin(phi)*sin(theta), dist*cos(phi), dist*sin(phi)*cos(theta), 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0 );

   glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
   glDisable( GL_BLEND );

   glBegin( GL_LINES );

      glColor3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
      glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
      glVertex3f( 0.5f, 0.0f, 0.0f );

      glColor3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
      glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
      glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.5f, 0.0f );

      glColor3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
      glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
      glVertex3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.5f );

   glEnd();

   glBegin( GL_QUADS );

      glColor4f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f , 0.0f);
      glVertex3f( -1.0f,  -0.2f,  1.0f );
      glVertex3f(  1.0f,  -0.2f,  1.0f );
      glVertex3f(  1.0f,  -0.2f, -1.0f );
      glVertex3f( -1.0f,  -0.2f, -1.0f );

      glColor4f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f , 0.0f );
      glVertex3f(  1.0f, -2.0f,  1.0f );
      glVertex3f(  1.0f, -2.0f, -1.0f );
      glVertex3f(  1.0f, -0.2f, -1.0f );
      glVertex3f(  1.0f, -0.2f,  1.0f );

      glColor4f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f , 0.0f );
      glVertex3f( -1.0f, -2.0f,  1.0f );
      glVertex3f( -1.0f, -2.0f, -1.0f );
      glVertex3f( -1.0f, -0.2f, -1.0f );
      glVertex3f( -1.0f, -0.2f,  1.0f );

      glColor4f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f , 1.0f );
      glVertex3f(  1.0f, -2.0f, -1.0f );
      glVertex3f( -1.0f, -2.0f, -1.0f );
      glVertex3f( -1.0f, -0.2f, -1.0f );
      glVertex3f(  1.0f, -0.2f, -1.0f );

   glEnd();

   glPushMatrix();
      drawParticles();
      glScalef(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
      drawParticles();
   glPopMatrix();


   glutSwapBuffers();
}
```

I am open to any kind of suggestions even involving shaders (but I would be interested to know if it is even possible to do with just plain OpenGL).

**UPDATE**:

Maybe I was unclear, I'm not necessarily interested in a strictly fixed-pipeline solution, I want to know how to manage additive blending in a scene even it means adding shaders code to my project.

Now, as Columbo pointed out, enabling the depth testing and disabling the depth writing solved my second problem. Now concerning the additive blending issue, I still have no clue about how to manage additive blending in a scene. Even though there might not such basic colors in a scene, the problem still remains as the flame will still be white and I'm open to know what I have to do with the pixel shader as suggested.

Comment: "with just plain OpenGL": OpenGL 2.1+ it *is* plain OpenGL to write shaders.

Comment: @CoffeeandCode I thought we could distinguish OpenGL from shaders by referring to shaders with the GLSL. Sorry for the misleading employed term... Anyway, what I meant is that I didn't write any shader for this and was wondering if it would be possible without _writing shaders_.

Comment: If you're learning OpenGL and want to actually use your knowledge in the future, I'd recommend you forgot all of your fixed-function stuff and learnt only OpenGL 3.3 core profile and do extension testing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. For the additive blending issue, it may not be a problem. You'll never have a block of cyan in a real scene. However, if you really really need a solution, you could try a premultiplied alpha blend (glBlendFunc(GL_ONE,GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);), then you have a bit more control. In your pixel shader you can multiply the output RGB by the source alpha manually, then you can choose the output alpha. An output alpha of zero produces an additive blend like you have at the moment. Outputting the full alpha value (vertex alpha * texture alpha) gives you a standard modulating alpha blend. You might be able to find some value in-between those two extremes which darkens the background enough to make your flame look yellow even against a cyan background without making it look rubbish. If you're not using pixel shaders, I believe it'd be possible with the fixed function pipeline by manipulating your texture during texture loading. It's all rather fiddly, and I'd suggest it's not worth doing, because you won't have such primary colours in a finished, lit scene. The more correct solution is to use HDR and tone mapping, but that's getting into some quite advanced rendering techniques.
2. Fixing the depth problem is simple. You need to enable depth testing for your flame, but disable depth writing. glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST) and glDepthMask(GL_FALSE) are the relevant commands.

Comment: Thanks! As you mentioned glDepthMask(GL_FALSE) solved the depth problem. Concerning the blending, I tried the premultiplied alpha blend as you suggested only using the fixed function pipeline and lost the additive effect... also the textures I'm using have black surroundings which alter the final effect... what kind of manipulations are you referring to when loading textures? Also, I'm a newbie concerning shaders, could you link me to any reference with an example or explaining how to achieve the pixel shader processing you're talking about? Thanks for the hint on HDR and tone mapping!